# Hide comment box from node for Anonymous users

Tags: 8, entities, hooks, comments

**I am trying to hide the comment box for anonymous users. Anonymous users should only be able to view the comments. How can I hide the comment form?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment module provides a permission, "Post comments" (`post comments`). Before using any code option, you should remove that permission for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

I added this inside my hook and it worked:

```
if($form_id == 'comment_comment_form') 
    {
        if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) 
        {
           $form['comment_body']['#access'] = FALSE;
         }

     }
```

Comment: If the default "Post comments" permission isn't enough to handle your needs, you should consider creating your own permission in a custom module and checking if the user has the permission (vs checking for a specific role). It's pretty easy to add a permission, see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/214501/48114