# Need to add multiple roles to routing.yml file

Tags: 8

I want to assign multiple roles in my routing.yml file :

requirements:
_role: "['role1', 'role2', 'role3']"

This is what I currently have, and it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how to add this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use permissions, not roles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly advise using permissions, not roles. Permissions are super simple to create in D8+, see [How do you create a custom permission to administer a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214500/how-do-you-create-a-custom-permission-to-administer-a-custom-module)

The [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes) documentation says:

> **_role:** A specific Drupal role, for example 'administrator'. You can specify multiple ones via "," for AND and "+" for OR logic.

> For example, `_role: organizer,participant,controller` means a Drupal user needs to have all three roles to access the page.
> Note that, since the roles available may differ between sites, it's recommended to use permission-based access restriction when possible.

So if a user needs all three roles, it's:

```
_role: 'role1,role2,role3'
```

or if they just need one of the three roles, it's:

```
_role: 'role1+role2+role3'
```